# Batch Geocoding with googleway R

Tags: r, geocoding, google-geocoder, googleway

I'm having trouble using the google_geocode function in the googleway package to batch geocode. I'd like to input a data frame of addresses and have the latitude and longitude coordinates returned for each.  The number of addresses is far beyond Google's 2,500 daily query limit, so the solution needs to use an API key to allow the purchase of more queries.

```
## Your Google API key
key<-"<insert key here>"
###  Make Data Frame with two observations
Dt<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(" 4605 Langdon ST , Fernley , NV , 89408", -119.2026,
          " 350 Quivera LN , Sparks , NV , 89441", NA), ncol=2)) 
###Change Column Names
colnames(Dt)<-c("address", "longitude")

### Make address column character
Dt$address<-as.character(Dt$address)

### Make data frame with one observation
dt<-Dt[1,]


### geocode one observation with googleway  This Works!!
google_geocode(address = dt[,"address"],
           key = key)  

### batch geocode 
res <- apply(Dt, 1, function(Dt){

google_geocode(address=list(Dt[,"address"]),
              key = key)
})

##  Error in Dt[, "address"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Please update your question to reflect what'd like to have happen. If you're trying to find ways to circumvent Google's limitations, you're likely going to have a difficult time ahead of you.

Comment: I don't intend to circumvent Google's limitations, which is why I need a solution that uses my API key so I will be able to receive and be billed for more than 2,500 results per day.   Sorry I wasn't clear, I thought batch geocoding described my need; I would get the latitude and longitude coordinates for several (thousands) addresses stored in a data frame.

Comment: @TFerrell - this question is specific to the R package `googleway`, so it's 'clear' if you're familiar with one/both of those

Comment: Here's another way using tidyverse functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680598/how-to-batch-geocode-using-googleway-with-tidyverse-functions/55680599#55680599

Answer (score 4):

The way you've constructed your data.frame seems a bit convoluted, so I'm re-doing it here

```
dt <- data.frame(address = c("4605 Langdon St, Fernley, NV, 89408", 
                             "350 Quivera Ln, Sparks, NV, 89441"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then you can use an `*apply` method to geocode each one

```
library(googleway)

key <- 'api_key'

res <- apply(dt, 1, function(x){
  google_geocode(address = x[['address']],
                 key = key)
})

str(res)
# List of 2
# $ :List of 2
# ..$ results:'data.frame': 1 obs. of  5 variables:
#   .. ..$ address_components:List of 1
# .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ long_name : chr [1:8] "4605" "Langdon Street" "Fernley" "Lyon County" ...
# .. .. .. ..$ short_name: chr [1:8] "4605" "Langdon St" "Fernley" "Lyon County" ...
# .. .. .. ..$ types     :List of 8
# .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "street_number"
# .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "route"
# ... etc
```

---

You can then extract the coordinates for each result and do whatever you want with it...

```
coords <- lapply(res, function(x){
  x$results$geometry$location
})

coords <- lapply(seq_along(res), function(x){
  coords <- res[[x]]$results$geometry$location
  address <- dt[x, 'address']
  res_df <- data.frame(lat = coords[, 'lat'],
                       lon = coords[, 'lng'], 
                       address = address
                       )
})

df_coords <- do.call(rbind, coords)
df_coords
#        lat       lon                             address
# 1 39.59275 -119.2026 4605 Langdon St, Fernley, NV, 89408
# 2 39.68911 -119.6345   350 Quivera Ln, Sparks, NV, 89441

mapKey <- symbolix.utils::mapKey()

google_map(key = mapKey) %>%
  add_markers(data = df_coords, lat = "lat", lon = "lon", info_window = "address")
```

[image]

---

Notes:

If you wanted to be 'sure' that the coordinates lined up with the input addresses, you should construct your results inside the `*apply` that does the geocoding.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when there are some addresses that google can't geocode.

Comment: @user3342735 you'll need to implement some error handling to resolve that.