# How to batch geocode using googleway with tidyverse functions?

Tags: r, googleway

I was looking for a way to do batch geocoding using `googleway`'s `google_geocode()`, which is only able to return one result at a time. I wanted to use tidyverse functions, and other answers made use of the older and more confusing `apply` family of functions.

Comment: @Samuel Liew deleted my answer, so I guess I can't share the solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using tidyverse functions.

This gets the geocode and also the formatted address in case you want it (other components of the result can be returned as well, they just need to be added to the table in the last row of the map function that gets returned.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(googleway))

set_key("your key here")

df <- tibble(full_address = c("2379 ADDISON BLVD HIGH POINT 27262", 
                                      "1751 W LEXINGTON AVE HIGH POINT 27262", "dljknbkjs"))

df %>% 
  mutate(geocode_result = map(full_address, function(full_address) {
    res <- google_geocode(full_address) 

    if(res$status == "OK") {

      geo <- geocode_coordinates(res) %>% as_tibble()

      formatted_address <- geocode_address(res)

      geocode <- bind_cols(geo, formatted_address = formatted_address)
    }
    else geocode <- tibble(lat = NA, lng = NA, formatted_address = NA)

    return(geocode)

  })) %>%
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   full_address                  lat   lng formatted_address                
#>   <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                            
#> 1 2379 ADDISON BLVD HIGH POI…  36.0 -80.0 2379 Addison Blvd, High Point, N…
#> 2 1751 W LEXINGTON AVE HIGH …  36.0 -80.1 1751 W Lexington Ave, High Point…
#> 3 dljknbkjs                    NA    NA   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>